# Is there any way to host total-flow application in Internet Information Services in windows?

Tags: javascript, iis, total.js

Is there any way to host total-flow application in Internet Information Services in  windows?

Comment: Hi there. Unfortunately it seems that your question is quite unspecific. Please provide more details: Here is the guide for "how to ask a good question on stackoverflow": https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Follow instructions here: https://docs.totaljs.com/latest/en.html#pages~Troubleshooting~(hosting-total-js-applications-in-iis-on-windows). I belive that it will work.

Comment: Got this Error:  
iisnode encountered an error when processing the request.

HRESULT: 0x2
HTTP status: 500
HTTP subStatus: 1001
HTTP reason: Internal Server Error
You are receiving this HTTP 200 response because system.webServer/iisnode/@devErrorsEnabled configuration setting is 'true'.

(node:13720) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.

Comment: Total.js +v3 uses a new implementation of Buffer, so reinstall/update Total.js framework from NPM or download it directly from GitHub. We need to test Total.js on Windows (but I don't have any idea when I can test it...). I recommend to use Linux/Unix.